# The advantage of HWUI rendering and overdraw

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

Is the HWUI rendering and the GPU Overdraw tool from app developer options useful with Jetpack Compose?

I tried it out, and some areas were seen to be overdrawing, and it seems like it is useful, but I might be wrong.

I don't see anyone using these tools for Jetpack Compose so really confused there.